# Magento - Get Manufacturer attribute's value List, Even if any Manufacturer is selected as filter

Tags: magento, filter, attributes, magento-1.7

I am using Magento 1.7

I want to Get Manufacturer attribute's value List, **Even if any Manufacturer is selected as filter**

If my category page is for example say :
http://www.magento.com/index.php/categoryPage.html?manufacturer=145

I am not able to get "manufacturer" attribute value's List on this particular page.

**As Manufacturer is passed as query string, It would be selected as filter.**
But I need that list any how.

when I use the code from *filter.phtml*, I got Error message in Log :

**"You cannot define a correlation name 'manufacturer_idx' more than once"**

How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can  check the  current url contain manufacturer then on the list page you can filter the product with manufacturer attribute by using below code

$manufacturerId = 3;
$attributeCode = 'manufacturer';

$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
             ->addAttributeToFilter($attributeCode, $manufacturerId);

So it will display the list of product that contain the manufacturer attribute.